# What tools do I use to build a beautiful website/webapp like this?

Tags: web-apps, web-development

I'm a college student that has only used swing with Java and tkinter with Python and built really plain looking desktop apps (i.e. [a calculator](http://zetcode.com/img/gui/tkinter/calculator.png)).

I have some free time this semester and I want to build an interactive GUI/webapp (sorry if I'm not using the correct terminology) that looks something like: http://www.tankathon.com/teams/spurs

What technologies would I have to learn to build something like this? Would I be able to build it off Heroku, or would I have to learn html/css/javascript (or RoR?) to build something beautiful?

Thanks!

Comment: What exactly do you want to replicate about that example website? The way the text/colors/fonts look? Or the graph? Or how it uses real live data?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul having something interactive using live data. the live data part I already have implemented as a desktop app, i'm just not sure how to make a desktop app into a webapp and make it look nice

Answer (score 1):

Well, a bit of research (i.e. looking at the links and the javascript in the page source) show that the page is implemented using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [Highcharts.js](http://www.highcharts.com/).  So they would be some of the tools you could use to implement a page like this.  Another popular tool for responsive web design is [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/).

In fact, that website's "beautifulness" and responsiveness comes from the client-side code (JS and CSS) that is being used here ... and good web design skills / execution.  The choice of server-side framework (RoR, Heroku, whatever) is largely orthogonal.